# Naming Strategy for table and column names (Doctrine ORM)

Tags: php, doctrine-orm, doctrine, mezzio, naming-strategy

Is it possible to have a naming strategy take care of mapping table and column names in Doctrine ORM?

Right now all names are specified via annotation in the entity classes, e.g.

```
<?php

namespace App\Entity;

use DateTimeInterface;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity()
 * @ORM\Table(name="role")
 */
class Role
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id()
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="guid")
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="NONE")
     * @var string
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(name="created_at", type="datetime")
     * @var \DateTimeImmutable
     */
    private $createdAt;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(name="created_by", type="string")
     * @var string
     */
    private $createdBy;

    // [..]

}
```

Table and column names are all `snake_case` while class and property names are all `camelCase`.

I've tried to remove table and column name declarations in the entity classes and provided a naming strategy` via configuration, trying to set it in the following two ways.

```
<?php

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping\UnderscoreNamingStrategy;

return [
    'doctrine' => [
        'connection' => [
            // [..]
        ],
        'driver' => [
            // [..]
        ],
        'annotation' => [
            // [..]
        ],
        'entity_managers' => [
            'default' => [
                'naming_strategy' => UnderscoreNamingStrategy::class,
            ],
        ],
        'orm' => [
            'naming_strategy' => UnderscoreNamingStrategy::class,
        ],
    ],
];
```

When trying to retrieve an entity, an error is thrown.

```
Doctrine\DBAL\Exception\InvalidFieldNameException: An exception occurred while executing &#039;SELECT t0.id AS id_1, t0.createdAt AS createdAt_2, t0.createdBy AS createdBy_3, t0.updatedAt AS updatedAt_4, t0.updatedBy AS updatedBy_5, t0.name AS name_6, t0.desc AS desc_7, t0.isCore AS isCore_8 FROM Role t0&#039;:

SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column &#039;t0.createdAt&#039; in &#039;field list&#039; in file C:\project\path\vendor\doctrine\dbal\lib\Doctrine\DBAL\Driver\AbstractMySQLDriver.php on line 60
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a bit of studying and experimenting, I got the following solution to work in a Zend Expressive application.

Configure naming strategy in **doctrine.local.php**

```
<?php

declare(strict_types = 1);

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping\UnderscoreNamingStrategy;

return [
    'doctrine' => [
        'connection' => [
            // [..]
        ],
        'driver' => [
            // [..]
        ],
        'annotation' => [
            // [..]
        ],
        'configuration' => [
            'orm_default' => [
                'naming_strategy' => UnderscoreNamingStrategy::class,
            ],
        ],
    ],
];
```

Implement a factory for the naming strategy

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Interop\Container\ContainerInterface;
use Zend\ServiceManager\Factory\FactoryInterface;

class NamingStrategyFactory implements FactoryInterface
{
    public function __invoke(ContainerInterface $container, $requestedName, array $options = null)
    {
        return new $requestedName();
    }
}
```

Register factory in **ConfigProvider.php**

```
<?php

declare(strict_types = 1);

namespace App;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping\UnderscoreNamingStrategy;

class ConfigProvider
{
    public function __invoke()
    {
        return [
            'dependencies' => $this->getDependencies(),
        ];
    }

    public function getDependencies(): array
    {
        return [
            'invokables' => [
            ],
            'factories' => [
                // [..]
                UnderscoreNamingStrategy::class => NamingStrategyFactory::class,
            ],
        ];
    }

}
```